# Why was Fraktur abolished in Germany?

Tags: history, blackletter

Wikipedia’s take on the topic is roughly this:

> On January 3, 1941, the National Socialist German Workers' Party, or more precisely Martin Bormann, issued a circular to all public offices which declared Fraktur to be Jewish letters and prohibited their further use. German historian Albert Kapr has speculated that the régime had realized that Fraktur would inhibit communication in the territories occupied during World War II.

But this seems a strange reason for people that valued their own ideology over everything else. Especially the allegation of “Jewish letters” strikes me as odd, seeing how Fraktur originates in the early 16th century and was commissioned by Maximilian I, an emperor that kicked the Jews out of some regions in 1496 and in 1509 passed the “Imperial Confiscation Mandate” which ordered the destruction of all Jewish literature apart from the Bible. Seems pretty in line with what the National Socialist German Workers’ Party did.

So why was Fraktur abolished, then?

Comment: Hard to tell, actually the NSDAP people and their leader made a lot of nonsensical and unconscious moves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about **german language**. Probably better asked at SE history or such site.

Comment: It is not true that the NSDAP unanimously preferred Fraktur. Many Nazis were fans of it, but Hitler himself seems having preferred Antiqua. Remember that he was a fan of classical antiquity.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ NSDAP people is very nice :) but false. The NSDAP currently doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: I didn't vote for close, but I also think [history SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for the question.

Comment: @FrankAus5419135 What's wrong with it? They called themselves _**N**ational**s**ozialistische **D**eutsche **A**rbeiter**p**artei_ ? Did I say they still exist? (Not that there are still people with the same mindset nowadays)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ maybe I misunderstood the word 'actually'?

Comment: @FrankAus5419135 Probably. Maybe _"really"_ would have been the better choice. That's one of the big mistakes / confusions I still have in english language :-).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OK. No Problem. My english is not perfect, too.

Comment: "Actual" is a notorious false friend.

Comment: [Meta discussion on the on-topicness of this question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1360/2594).

Comment: Fraktur is curvy, baroque, it did not fit the Nazi canon of straight. Also, the Nazis wanted to make people forget the 1000 years of history of the first German Reich, and create a new 1000 year Reich instead.

Comment: @Janka _"it did not fit the Nazi canon of straight"_ What a nonsense! Sorry! Even pushing a particular typewriter brand seems to be more probable.

Comment: Some people really need <sarcasm> tags.

Comment: Ich finde die Frage sehr interessant und würde gerne einen Bonus darauf ausloben. Bitte wieder öffnen - natürlich geht es um deutsche Sprache. Die Frage ist besser als 90% dessen, was hier sonst so als Frage kursiert.

Comment: A very common theory is, that typewriters werde needed for the administration of the countries conquered. As all typewriters that were already there in those countries had Antiqua-types, and due to the war there were no capacitiys to produce Fraktura-Typewriters, they simply declared Fraktura to be "Non-Germanic".

Comment: Besonders schön ist, dass über dem Erlass von 1941 in schönsten Frakturlettern "Nationalsozialistische Arbeiterpartei Deutschlands" im Briefkopf steht, im Erlass aber "das Verbot der Judenlettern" ausgesprochen wird... http://www.uni-heidelberg.de/unimut/themen/fraktur-verbot.html und heute rechtsradikale Propagandablättchen die häufigsten Anwender sind.

Answer (score 11):

Es gibt mehrere Theorien über den möglichen Grund des Verbots:

1. Deutschland wollte zu einer Weltmacht aufsteigen, und seinen Einfluß (kulturell, politisch) in der Welt sichern. Mit Schrifttum, das im Ausland keiner lesen konnte, war das nach Ansicht der Regierung nicht zu erreichen.
   (http://www.uni-heidelberg.de/unimut/themen/fraktur-verbot.html)
2. Englisch, französisch und Latein wurden in Antiqua geschrieben, Deutsch nur in gebrochenen Schriften. Wer gebildet war, las in fremden Sprachen in Antiqua, Fraktur galt als prosaisch.
3. Hitler persönlich empfand Fraktur als altmodisch, Anqiqua als fortschrittlich: "[Eure vermeintliche gotische Verinnerlichung paßt schlecht in das Zeitalter von Stahl und Eisen, Glas, Beton, von Frauenschönheit und Männerkraft, von hochgehobenem Haupt und trotzigem Sinn](http://urholstein.de/geschichte-der-gebrochenen-schrift/)."
4. Es gab keine Schreibmaschinen, die gut lesbare Fraktur schreiben konnten. Für einen modernen, straff zentral orientierten Staat war die Schreibmaschine aber ein Muß. (Wikipedia-Artikel zu [Frakturtypen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibmaschinenschrift#Frakturtypen_f%C3%BCr_die_Schreibmaschine) für Schreibmaschinen)

Es ist heute schwer nachzuvollziehen, warum man Fraktur, die noch 30 Jahre vorher als Inbegriff der "deutschen Schrift" galt, plötzlich so verdammte und durch moderne serifenlose Schriften ersetzen wollte, die man zu Bauhauszeiten noch als "entartet" bezeichnet hatte. Ich tippe deshalb auf (3) als Hauptgrund.

Wenn man Gründe für nicht nachvollziehbare Entscheidungen sucht, fängt man, gerade in einer Diktatur, am besten "ganz oben" an - Ich könnte mir durchaus vorstellen, dass z.B.  auch die Tatsache, dass der Erlass dazu auf Briefpapier mit einem vorgedruckten Kopf *in Frakturschrift* geschrieben ist, ein Indiz  zivilen Ungehorsams ist, mit dem jemand (Bormann selbst, oder wer auch immer das Schreiben verfasst hat) zum Ausdruck gebracht hat, für wie großen Blödsinn er diese Entscheidung hielt. Liest man den zugehörigen [Erlass](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/Schrifterlass_Antiqua1941.gif) unter dieser Prämisse, findet man durchaus Hinweise, die auf eine gewisse Art von Distanzierung Bormanns zu dieser Entscheidung hindeuten könnten.

Interessant ist, dass im selben Zuge die großen Zeitungen der Schweiz Fraktur ebenfalls abschaffen mussten, weil es keine Lettern mehr dafür aus Deutschland zu kaufen gab (Wikipedia-Artikel zum "[Normalschrifterlaß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiqua-Fraktur-Streit#Normalschrifterlass)").

Comment: Ein guter Beginn. Ist es eigentlich Zufall, dass Dein Avatar wie ein stilisiertes Hakenkreuz aussieht? Punkt 3. sieht wie ein Zitat aus - wo stammt es her? Punkt 4: Gibt es einen Grund, wieso man Schreibmaschinen nicht mit Frakturtypen bauen konnte - zu viele Ligaturen? Ähnlich mutet der Nachsatz merkwürdig an - wieso konnten die Schweizer nicht selbst Lettern produzieren?

Comment: @userunknown  Da mußt du SE fragen - es ist der Stock-Avatar, mit dem jeder anfängt. Lass' dir ausserdem zu deiner Phantasie gratulieren... (4) ist sicher eine neue Frage, aber nicht hier. Und die Schweizer bauten wohl lieber Uhren statt Lettern.

Comment: Die Avatare kommen von [Gravatar](https://de.gravatar.com/). Wer dort kein Bild eingestellt hat bzw. nicht registriert ist, bekommt ein aus dem Hash-Wert seiner Email-Adresse berechnetes "Identicon" zugewiesen.